# Atomic Add on Cuda not working..

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-atomics

My problem is to find out the number of integer points in n dimensional sphere using CUDA. I dont understand what is wrong with the below code but it is giving 0 output all the time. CUDA compute capability is 2.0 and tool kit version is 3.10.
Thanks for all the help.

```
__global__ void count_in(int pow_rad, int ndim,int *digit,int w,unsigned int *count,double radius)
{


long int i,j;
int rem,idx,sq,num;
int iy=blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
int ix=blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
int width=gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
int h=2*w+1;
i=iy*width+ix;
if(i>pow_rad) return;

    sq=0;
    idx=0;
    num=i;
    for(j=0;j<ndim;j++)
        {digit[j]=0;}
    while(num!=0)
    {
        rem=num%w;
        num/=w;
        digit[idx]=rem;
        idx++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<ndim;j++)
        {sq+=(digit[j]-h)*(digit[j]-h);}
    if(sq<(radius*radius))
        atomicInc(count,(unsigned int)1);
    __syncthreads();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
const long ntrials = 5;
int i;
for (int n = 0; n < ntrials; ++n) {
    int *digit;
    unsigned int *count;
    std::cout<<n<<std::endl;
    int pow_rad;
    unsigned int num;
    // Select radius and number of dimensions at random
    const double r = drand48() * (RMAX - RMIN) + RMIN;
    const int   nd = lrand48() % (MAXDIM - 1) + 1;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &digit,sizeof(int)*nd);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &count,sizeof(unsigned int));
    cudaMemset(count,0,sizeof(unsigned int));
    int h=(int)floor(r);
    int w=2*h+1;
    std::cout << "###"<< r <<" "<< nd<< std::endl;
    for(i=1;i<=nd;i++)
        pow_rad*=w;
    int width=(int)sqrt(pow_rad);
    // Call your function
    dim3 dimBlock(32,32);
    dim3 dimGrid((width/32)+1,(width/32)+1);

count_in<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(pow_rad, nd,digit,w,count,r);
    cudaMemcpy(&num,count,sizeof(unsigned int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
std::cout << "-->"<<num << std::endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe a litte more explanation on your code would be advised. Stackoverflow is a community [not a debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to the community and didn't realise. What I am trying to do here is convert the number to base 2H+1 so that I can check if the point is inside the sphere. My sequential version of the program is giving results, but when I do this all I get is zero. I am new to CUDA as well. Thanks for the help

Comment: no problem. My comment was just to help you improve your question ;) The more precise, the more detailed answers you will get.

Comment: The code you have posted is not complete and will not compile. It is very hard to diagnose problems when there isn't the *actual* code you are compiling and running in the question

Comment: Also, are you in the habit of ignoring compiler warnings? Because I see at least one uninitialised variable being passed to your kernel as an argument

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at all of your code, but the lines

```
    atomicInc(count,(unsigned int)1);
```

seems to show a common misunderstanding of the atomicInc function.  The second argument is not the amount to increment, but the modulus; when the global variable reaches that amount, it resets to zero.  With the value you specified, each time the statement executes the variable `count` is reset to 0.

If you change atomicInc to atomicAdd, or if you change the modulus to something large enough that it will never be reached, it should work better.

Comment: While this is true and a very valid point, I'm fairly certain that the `atomicInc` statement in the kernel never gets executed because the kernel blows up with out of bounds memory access before it is reached.